# How to get TSC to narrow a union type between a function and a Record with a discriminatory property and retain a proper error message

Tags: typescript

**Edit**: Comments on this post might not make sense to new readers because of the vast amount of changes that the post went through over its lifetime. Refer to the history if you are confused.

Here are some types which we will refer to in the question (find on [tsplayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdiGBjYBLA9nKBeAUFAqAbylEgC4oAiASQDkBhKgbigF8oAffQksiSlQAiAUSasO3QsVLgB1AMoiAKgH0AajAAyAVREsoYAIYgANuiMATSnACuAWwBGEAE4SuPAnzmCFAeQBZEVU-ZQAJEQAlVRgGZRo-OgMACyMAZxEAD2AXI0pHdHRTCCM4CVxcfihlZNs4AGtkNEwcKAAKAEocAD4oAAUXdHtUNIgAHlKQboqqpow4BhcS4HQXVs6e2AQ5ls5q2oaduAqkTDTgKABzQutYFHnF5dX1ruxetu8KRRUNbT0qAA0hhM5islAAjAAmADM7A6uFOcHOUCMpjS6AA6qt6mlKEdHkYVmtsO1Xu8yf1BsNRgA6Jbo0wANwgbSh0PhiORcHQOjg80oGzeW0Q9xaJMF70+8ioGMiiQA4lQ4RUAPQq6pyKAAchlcroiq1UBGUG5F3SaVQlzgRkcxVI6FkkG1VH8QRC4SiMTiCSSWppCLOF0KYFxd2aCyWhOe4opH0d0tlCqVbA6QA)):

```
type AnyAction =
  { type: "INC"; } |
  { type: "DEC"; } |
  { type: "SET_VALUE"; payload: number; } |
  { type: "SOME_OTHER_ACTION"; hasExtra: boolean; }

type ThunkAction = () => Promise<any>

type ActionCreator = () => AnyAction | ThunkAction
```

The idea behind `ActionCreator` is to provide a uniform approach to creating "actions" that will be dispatched to the Redux store (which is implemented to allow for thunks). A user would always "invoke" an action creator and dispatch the result to the store. The result as such can be either `AnyAction` or `ThunkAction`.

However, there are weird behaviours when we define `ActionCreator` in such a way, and they seem to appear due to a union between a `AnyAction` and `ThunkAction` as TSC is not able to properly narrow down what is the return type of an `ActionCreator` (at least to my understanding)

For example:

```
const good: ActionCreator = () => ({ type: "SET_VALUE", payload: 123 })
const alsoWorks: ActionCreator = () => () => Promise.resolve(123)
```

This works well, TSC even has good autocomplete, suggests the types, constraints the payload to a number, etc.

To showcase what is an expected (or rather, **WANTED**) behavior I will also demonstrate what happens once we DO NOT USE a union:

```
// We get a good error message
const noUnion: () => AnyAction = () => ({ type: "WRONG" })
// Type '"WRONG"' is not assignable to type '"INC" | "DEC" | "SET_VALUE" | "SOME_OTHER_ACTION"'
```

However once we have a union between `AnyAction` and `ThunkAction` as a return type for our `ActionCreator` the error message gets some weird behaviour:

```
// TSC recognizes this as an error, but gives a less then ideal message
const oops: ActionCreator = () => ({ type: "WRONG" })
// Type '"WRONG"' is not assignable to type '"SOME_OTHER_ACTION"'.
```

##### Question:

How would I define the `ActionCreator` or (as discussed in comments) change the `ThunkAction` type in order to allow TSC to give a message as shown in the "showcase" even for a union return type for an `ActionCreator`?

Comment: I will ammend the whole question, I've stumbled upon one discovery as I was fiddling with it post-ask. Will be done in 15ish minutes.

Comment: Is this a better post now?

Comment: Alright, let me give it another shot, will remove the less improtant one completely

Comment: Alright, I've cut it down completely and tried to define as much as possible, if this still is not something that you can help with, I guess its a lost cause - I don't know how to make it more well defined

Comment: Much appreciated. What I've meant to say is, that I don't know how to make this more clear then it is now, and if it is still not your cup of tea then it never will be. Sure someone else might take a look, everyone's welcome. You've been a godsent for past couple of issues I've had. I can't explain how grateful I am - I can honestly say that your responses are probably the reason I am trying to get this thing working, and haven't given up months ago. If I could hire you for consulting on this whole project I would do it in a blink of an eye - I am in a dire need of someone with your skills

Comment: It can be reduced to that example, yes. Though I'd note that this only happens when there is a union, without a union, it works as it did before. Maybe there is a way to tell the compiler its now a narrowed type ? Refactoring of types? I am not on the third iteration refactoring all the types in the project, this might not be an issue.

Comment: I think I've found a solution by changing the `ThunkAction` type, but I am not sure how this type will reflect on the system. Take a look at [this](https://tsplay.dev/NBVLVN) and tell me do you think this change would significantly change the semantics of what `Fn` type is? as in would it cause issues down the line?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.  I wanted to use Exclude to "remove" anything that is not a function, but essentially what you said works, I will edit the question to be a minimum reproducable, you may create an asnwer, Thanks <3

Comment: My apologies. I figgured that once we exclude the function, the error message disappears, and as such it wasn't relevant anymore. I will rewrite the question to emphasize the message part again.

Comment: Better? I am sorry for the mess. Do you want me to further abstract it to a `AnyAction | Fn` or is the `ThunkAction` type okay for you>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, `AnyAction` is a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) type, but `AnyAction | ThunkAction` is not because `ThunkAction` doesn't explicitly mention the `type` discriminant.  It's a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), but not a discriminated union.

TypeScript tends to do a reasonably good job of producing a readable error if you have an invalid value of a discriminated union type, but when you have an invalid value of an arbitrary union, then the error is sometimes not what people expect.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#37488](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37488) and [microsoft/TypeScript#53258](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/52358) for examples.

The underlying issue is that, if a value is supposed to be of type `A | B | C | ⋯ | Z` but fails to be, it's because the value fails to be an `A` *and* it fails to be a `B` *and* it fails to be a `C`, et cetera.  If you fixed even one of those failures, the error would go away.  But the compiler can't possibly write an error message that details all of those (e.g., "your value isn't an `A` because you put a `string` where you were supposed to put a `number` *and* it isn't a `B` because you forgot the `b` property *and* ... *and* it isn't a `Z` because it's not an array, so you should fix one of these.")  Instead it just picks one of the union members and gives you the error for that one, usually the last one, (e.g., "your value isn't a `Z` because it it's not an array").  There's nothing necessarily *incorrect* about that message; after all, if you fixed that, the error would go away.  It's just that it might not be the most relevant piece of information for someone trying to understand what went wrong.

---

In the absence of language changes to improve error messages, one approach you could take would be to turn `AnyAction | ThunkAction` into a genuine discriminated union by making sure that `ThunkAction`'s declaration explicitly prohibits having a defined `type` value.  Like this, for example:

```
type ThunkAction = { (): Promise<any>, type?: never }
```

(That's the equivalent of `(() => Promise<any>) & {type?: never}`, but it's packaged in a single type.)  Note that you can't really prohibit a property in TypeScript; the closest you can come is to make an [optional property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) whose value is [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type), so the only value that could possibly be there is `undefined`.

Once we do that, we get a more readable error:

```
const oops: ActionCreator = () => ({ type: "WRONG" });
// Type '"WRONG"' is not assignable to type 
// '"INC" | "DEC" | "SET_VALUE" | "SOME_OTHER_ACTION" | undefined'.
```

Since `"WRONG"` is none of possible discriminant types, which now includes `undefined`, the compiler can issue an error saying that.  And hopefully this doesn't change the semantics of the code elsewhere. Your examples still work correctly, at least:

```
const alsoWorks: ActionCreator = () => () => Promise.resolve(123) // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdiGBjYBLA9nKBeAUASAG8pRIAuKAIgEkA5AYUoG4oBfKAHwONIgsoAiAUUYt2XIiXB8qAZSEAVAPoA1GABkAqkOZQwAQxAAbdPoAmFOAFcAtgCMIAJzGduU8nIDyAWSFLPCgASQgBKSjD0CtSetLoAFvoAzkIAHsCO+hR26OhGEPpwYri4vFAKcVZwANbIaJg4UMQAFACUFAAKjug2qIkQADwFIAB8ADTuEAD8lhAAbk5sxaW1GHD0jvnA6I4NrTjDsAgr9RxlFdXHcMVImInAUADmORawKKvrm9u7LftQTTzSfjyZRqLQ6cYGYymF4ARgATABmNgtXA3OB3KD6IyJdAAdW2VUSFEuH30Wx22D+P2wBz2NKgnW6vQgADoNjijPMmvCESjcAB6flQXHQB4Qe76R7PKBOLo7GwQRKJfRi1G3e5wdCaOCrCh0g7wRBveqU-V-AEeSi4kIxADilGR13VUByYCJrzqaw2ZK+puptItMitNto9uRTAFQoU0igAHJg3bKLGoL0oJqJUrUA84Po7HkSOgJlBI3GaAwHadBCIK3JFKoNNoa5RZD4-AFgmEIlEYjXKmYIAAzVBwCBmWMs4q4AeVY1YOI2GxNFIUZptBldHp9QYIMYTaZQSpVTUAdywrB+hAIaIxmQ97295O+vxSEfw+lwrCAA)